# How to make js run after php input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i tried to add datatables to my web, but i have a problem that is the code will not apply the js code after finishing input which have HTML and PHP.
This is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                header: function ( row ) {
                    var data = row.data();
                    return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                }
            } ),
            renderer: function ( api, rowIdx, columns ) {
                var data = $.map( columns, function ( col, i ) {
                    return '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+col.title+':'+'</td> '+
                            '<td>'+col.data+'</td>'+
                        '</tr>';
                } ).join('');

                return $('<table class="table"/>').append( data );
            }
        }
    }
} );
} );
```

And this is my html code:

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>STT</th>
            <th>Tên sản phẩm</th>
            <th>Ngày sản xuất</th>
            <th>Mã sản phẩm</th>
            <th>Vị trí lắp đặt</th>
            <th>Chủng loại</th>
            <th>Nhóm</th>
            <th>Dự án</th>
            <th>Nhà sản xuất</th>
            <th>Miêu tả sản phẩm</th>
            <th>Lỗi</th>
            <th>Cấp độ</th>
            <th>Miêu tả lỗi</th>
            <th>Người khắc phục</th>
            <th>Thời gian khắc phục</th>
            <th>Chi tiết lỗi</th>
            <th style="width:1%; text-align:center">Hành động</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
```

And this is the php code

```
$stt= 1;
    $sql= "SELECT * from fixed ORDER BY sta ASC, level ASC";
    //thuc hien cau lenh voi bien conn lay tu file connection.php
    $query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $stt++?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["ten_sp"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["ngay_sx"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["ma_sp"]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["vitrilapdat"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["chungloai"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["nhom"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["d_an"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["nhasx"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["mieuta"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["loi"] ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php
            if($data["level"] == 1){
                echo '<p style="color: red;">Khẩn cấp</p>';
            }else if($data["level"] == 2){
                echo '<p style="color: #00b300;">Quan trọng</p>';
            } else if($data["level"] == 3){
                echo '<p style="color: #0000cc;">Cần lưu ý</p>';
            }
                        ?>  
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $data["mieutaloi"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["nguoikhacphuc"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["thoigian"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data["chitiet"] ?></td>
        <td><a href="prod_fixed_editinfo.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"]?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">
            <?php 
            if($data["sta"] == 1){

                    echo "Un-read";
                    }else{
                        echo "Read";
                        } ?></a></td>

        <td><a href="prod_fixed_delete.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"]?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Xóa</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

And this is the result i get:
[image]

I want the result like this:
[image]

This is the code of this pic: (The same js and style as the first pic)

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vivian</td>
            <td>Harrell</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td>2009/02/14</td>
            <td>$452,500</td>
            <td>9422</td>
            <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
            <td>9422</td>
            <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
            <td>9422</td>
            <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna</td>
            <td>Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
            <td>4226</td>
            <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
            <td>9422</td>
            <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
             <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I think the problem here is the js code will not run after input all the info from php code, but i dont know how to fix that, can you help?

Comment: what is your problem? what issue you are having with this?

Comment: php is processed before the page is even sent to the client where the Javascript is run.
Where is the element with id example to which you apply your datatables? jQuery usually fails quietly when the selector engine finds no elements

Comment: I take it from the official website of datatables
I think it come from this: https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
Or this:

Comment: You do call your jQuery code on document ready, so maybe it's just a selector that's wrong. Use more logging is my tip!

Comment: @ParthTrivedi the problem here is the php is processed before the page is even sent to the client where the Javascript is run. SO that the display is not as i expected, can you help

Comment: @Thomas yeah, i did call Js but it not run, so that the interface is so bad, i want to have the interface like in the second picture (the code in that just use js and html and no php)

Comment: "... php is processed before the page is even sent to the client..." yes that's how it works, are you sure your dom contains node with `examle` id?

Comment: @cske But why my code does not show the interface like in the second pic? The code in the second pic, i just use html and js and it works, but when i try to input php as my code, it did not work as i expected

Comment: basing from your 2 images.  It's a totally different arrangement? or maybe you are talking about your design for your 1st image?

Comment: I did upload the code for the second image, can you take a look and help me solve my problems @roullie

Comment: table node is missing shoud be `<table id="example">`

Comment: @roullie the data in the first image is my data from database while the second image is the thing i imported from the code.

Comment: @cske I did add the id for the table like that, but it is not work. And i dont know why

Comment: Can you open the DOM explorer and copy the actual table structure your php code generates? Could be the php generates a faulty table that the Javascript cannot work with correctly.

Comment: I removed  -FIXED from the title in an edit. If you fixed it yourself, either post your own answer or delete the question. Accepting an answer marks it as being fixed/solved.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- i did add a comment to show what is the problem and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ First, check again the element id #example, do you have it or not, it must be some things like:

```
<table id="example">

 <thread>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
  </tr>      
 </thread>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
  </tr>      
 </tbody>

</table>
```

2/ Second, make sure you add the link to DataTable js to the page with the right path, for example:

```
<link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/yourscript.js"></script>
```

3/ Third, try to remove the php code, create a normal table, to see if the js work or not..?

Comment: Hello, i pretty sure that i did all the thing you listed out correctly, The problem here is, The code run well when the table was created by just html and no php, however when i create table by html and php (like my code), it can not run (it run but the interface i got does not like the thing i got when the table was created by html)

Comment: Do you use any webserver like Wamp, Xampp ...etc, try to restart the services of those program, or open the page normally without using webserver (right click -> open with Google Chrome ..., for example), to see if it work or not ...

Comment: i use XAMPP and i restart it several times but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help, my code is wrong because I used order by in the select code and maybe also I added more `<td>` than `<th>`, I did realize it this morning.
Thank you a lot for helping me solve this problem.